# Android - always active else statement

Tags: android

```
  public void myClick1(View v){
    EditText txtUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.strUser);
    EditText txtPwd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.strPwd);

  if (txtUser.equals("admin")){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Authentication Pass", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not valid User ID/Password: " + txtUser.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

No matter what i key in into text box, it always active the else statement. Why?

Comment: Because txtUser is always an EditText not a String. You need to get the value out of the EditText (`txtUser.getText()`) before you check if it's equal.

Comment: An EditText cannot be ever equal to a String. Its content might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the text of the TextView, like this:

```
    EditText txtUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.strUser);
    EditText txtPwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.strPwd);

    if ("admin".equals(txtUser.getText().toString())) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication Pass", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not valid User ID/Password: " + txtUser.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use txtUser.getEditableText().toString() when comparing like this:

```
if ("admin".equals(txtUser.getEditableText().toString())){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Authentication Pass", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not valid User ID/Password: " + txtUser.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not familiar with android atm, but have you tried:

> *txtUser.getText() == "admin"*

Thanks for the comments (I was using C# approach), fixed code:

```
txtUser.getText().equals("admin")
```

Comment: This is wrong for a couple reasons. One being [how to compare strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)